# Read in Html text into label

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

Basically what I want to know is how to read into some HTML text into a label (I am scraping this off of a website) but I know that I can't convert a web element into a string. Any help?

Btw. I am very new to C#.

```
var points = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#site-header > div > div > div.col-xs-8.col-sm-8.col-md-8 > div > div.header-right.header-user-functions > div:nth-child(5) > a > span"));
CustomLabel7.Text = points;
```

Comment: What are you getting in 'points' right now?

Comment: Have you tried: driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#site-header > div > div > div.col-xs-8.col-sm-8.col-md-8 > div > div.header-right.header-user-functions > div:nth-child(5) > a > span")).toString(); ?

Comment: @A3006 I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' to 'sting' "

Comment: @DaveS Now it says IWebElement does not contain a definition to 'toString'. Am I missing a directive or assembly?

Comment: @Delvid Guerro  Thanks for telling me the name of your interface.  IWebElement has a method called Text, which is what you need. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

In the IWebElement Interface you are using there is a property Text which you can call to get your desired string:

Gets the innerText of this element, without any leading or trailing whitespace, and with other whitespace collapsed.

Source: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Text.htm

```
var points =  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#site-header > div > div > div.col-xs-8.col-sm-8.col-md-8 > div > div.header-right.header-user-functions > div:nth-child(5) > a > span"));

// perform some kind of check if points has valid data

if (points != null)
    CustomLabel7.Text = points.Text;
```

Comment: @DeividGuerrero - Glad to hear!

Answer (score 0):

get the text property of the element

```
    IWebElement point = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#site-header > div > div > div.col-xs-8.col-sm-8.col-md-8 > div > div.header-right.header-user-functions > div:nth-child(5) > a > span"));
if(point != null)
      CustomLabel7.Text = point.Text;
```